# how to mark two location's in map of an android app

Tags: android, dictionary

in my app i am showing the google maps. Here i want to mark two places. One is to be my current location place and other is to be the lat and lng which i give.

i am able to show the current location with a pin marked on it but how to mark another location in the same map......

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)..

In these page you have add you location in String array.. In these place you can add two Latitude and Longitude Values..So that it will points Two places in MapView..

```
 String coordinates[] = {"1.352566007", "103.78921587"};
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
```