# Android: Launching google map with intent how to mark a specific location

Tags: android

I am launching googlemap using an intent giving the latitude and longitude.
It shows the map with the area around specified location.

How can i get a marker displayed at this specific location while launching the map.

here is my code for starting the activity :

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("geo:" + lat+ "," + long+ "?z=10"  ) )
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @preeta You need to place markers using intents or without intents?

Comment: Follow this...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840943/how-to-mark-two-locations-in-map-of-an-android-app

Comment: I want to do it woth intents. It works with mapactivity and webview but here the requirement is specific to be with intent and launching an activity

Answer (score 3):

to place mark just use the following example:

```
// change name - to any text you want to display
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("geo:55.74274,37.56577?q=55.74274,37.56577 (name)"));
// the following line should be used if you want use only Google maps
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use static map api for...check this ..there are link to show mapview if acant work with intent ,You should add webview and loadurl its worked fine...

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Markers